# Sort an Object list with Collections having only list as parameter in Java

Tags: java, class, collections

I have an assignment says printing a object list with given main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ArrayList<LoaiPhong> ds = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("xx.in"));
    int n = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());
    while(n-->0){
        ds.add(new LoaiPhong(in.nextLine()));
    }
    Collections.sort(ds);                   //this only include object list
    for(LoaiPhong tmp : ds){
        System.out.println(tmp);
    }
}

static class LoaiPhong {
    String line;
    public LoaiPhong(String line) {
        this.line = line;
    }
}
```

So that's mean i have to do something outside the main class to sort the list. Can anyone suggest what to do to sort the object list by its property?

Edit: Thanks to Gus i have the answer, the new class look something like this

```
static class LoaiPhong implements Comparable<LoaiPhong> {
        ...
        @Override
        public int compareTo(LoaiPhong_.LoaiPhong o) {
            return <Some logic here>;
        }
}
```

Comment: `Collections.sort()` will sort that collection according to "natural ordering" according to the docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List).  So, you'll need to modify the `LoaiPhong` class such that implements `Comparable` and its `compareTo()` function provides the ordering you desire.  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

Comment: @Gus thanks for sharing knowledge ^^